# USB port forwarding in Ubuntu AWS machine from windows client

Tags: rdp, aws

I am trying to access my local USB devices from Remote Amazon AWS machine. for Windows remote AWS machine I was able to access it following these instructions: http://www.howtogeek.com/97987/how-to-forward-local-drives-to-remote-machines-using-remote-desktop/ 
But I am not able to access from Ubuntu remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

i will assume you are using *Remmina Remote Desktop Client* it's installed by default in ubuntu 14.04  , in the dash write *Remmina Remote Desktop Client* and open it

if not installed you can install it from Ubuntu Software Center

start a new connection

[image]

you will find the option to share folders from your local computer as in this photo

[image: Remote Connection Reference]

for more information about the connection you may check the following [Reference](http://www.7tutorials.com/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu)

Comment: Sharing folders is trivial, by now there should be a solution for UART or RS232C to USB.